# Update a primefaces tabView by absolute id from dialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a typical CRUD example: a user picks an item from a dataTable, a dialog opens and shows a form to edit the item. After saving I want to update the tabView which contains the dataTable. Unfortunately this isn't so easy I expected.
The dialog is included in the body after the main UI. Both, the tabView and the dialog are not display when the UIs start page is invoked. Exactly in this moment I get an exception about an unknwon id:

```
10:53:58,877 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-/0.0.0.0:9090-3) Error Rendering View[/views/main.xhtml]: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression ":searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId" referenced from "editPropertyFormId:j_idt101".
at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentInternal(SearchExpressionFacade.java:422) [primefaces-5.1.17.jar:5.1.17]
at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentForClient(SearchExpressionFacade.java:200) [primefaces-5.1.17.jar:5.1.17]
at org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponentsForClient(SearchExpressionFacade.java:147) [primefaces-5.1.17.jar:5.1.17]
at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addExpressions(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:92) [primefaces-5.1.17.jar:5.1.17]
at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:85) [primefaces-5.1.17.jar:5.1.17]
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:356) [primefaces-5.1.17.jar:5.1.17]
at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.buildRequest(CommandButtonRenderer.java:123) [primefaces-5.1.17.jar:5.1.17]
at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:65) [primefaces-5.1.17.jar:5.1.17]
```

So there are ids checked for not visible components?
The id of the tabView is

```
<div id="searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-hidden-container ui-tabs-top resultViewTabView"
```

I try to update it with

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{editPropertyBL.save()}" update=":searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId" resetValues="true" />
```

If I update the component from the backing beans save method with

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("searchInstancesFormId:listResultTabViewId");
```

it works. I am not a fan of static methods and this is not very comfortable for unit tests, so I am wondering why the pure xhtml update approach fails.
Can I infuence primefaces how it is checking the ids?

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: I gather that you're conditionally building the component tree using e.g. JSTL `<c:if>` instead of conditionally rendering the HTML output using JSF component's `rendered` attribute? I don't see other plausible explanation for this problem.

Comment: I have only one dialog which is initialized with the data of the selected row (not a dialog for each row)....just for clarification. Also the dialog has its own form and I have no nested forms in the whole application.

Comment: I have several reasons why I do not use the editing like in the primefaces showcase: validation, custom input elements (select elements from tree) and also show some content like pdfs and images inside the editing form. I also don't like when I open an edit dialog and loose the complete context and my dataList is not visible anymore like it will be with JSF navigation.

Comment: You are right BalusC. Inside the dialog I include a xhtml inside a p:layout or without the p:layout plain in the dialog. The user can switch the views. The problem was with rendered attribute I got a duplicate ids exception. Also with subView it didn't work. So I used c:if test... But I do not understand why this is a problem.